# Laravel 6 API request validate array of objects before saving

Tags: php, json, laravel-routing, laravel-6

**Problem**: How can I correctly validate an array of JSON objects sent via an API request?

**Situation**:

I sent a post request of an array of JSON objects to be saved. However, I cant make the validation work.

**JSON**

```
{
    "answers": [
        {
            "title": "hello World",
            "question_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "title": "hello World 2",
            "question_id": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Attempt #1**

```php
Route::post('answer/multiple', function (Request $request) {
    $answers = $request->answers;
    foreach ($answers as $answer) {
        $answer->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'question_id' => 'required',
        ]);
        $new_answer = new Answer();
        $new_answer->title = $answer['title'];
        $new_answer->question_id = $answer['question_id'];
        $new_answer->save();
    }
    return response()->json($request);
});
```

I also tried looping through each one to validate, sadly it does not work.

**Attempt #2**

```php
Route::post('answer/multiple', function (Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'answer.*.title' => 'required',
        'answer.*.question_id' => 'required',
    ]);
    $answers = $request->answers;
    foreach ($answers as $answer) {
        $new_answer = new Answer();
        $new_answer->title = $answer['title'];
        $new_answer->question_id = $answer['question_id'];
        $new_answer->save();
    }
    return response()->json($request);
});
```

In this one, the validation is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the `$this->validate()` controller method, the `Validator::make()` static function will not throw an error if validation fails.

You will need to check if it has failed and return the error messages using the `->fails()` Validator method:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'answer.*.title' => 'required',
    'answer.*.question_id' => 'required',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) { 
    return redirect('post/create')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}

foreach ($request->answers as $answer) {
    $new_answer = new Answer();
    $new_answer->title = $answer['title'];
    $new_answer->question_id = $answer['question_id'];
    $new_answer->save();
}

return response()->json($request);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `$this->validate()` method:

```
$validatedData = $this->validate($request, [
    'answer.*.title' => 'required',
    'answer.*.question_id' => 'required',
]);
```

Note that we use `$request` instead of `$request->all()`.

Also note that when using this method, you will get an array of answers in `$validatedData`, so you will need to change your code accordingly.

Comment: when I use "$this->validate()" your second example it returns error like "message": "Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteFileRegistrar::validate()"

Comment: Where are you calling the method? In your controller?

Comment: in the routes/api.php. I did not use controller. do I have to use controller to make this work?

Comment: This requires using a controller as it is a validate method

Comment: thanks, I added 's' to the 'answer.*.title' and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
$answer = [ 'answer' => $requests->all() ];


$validator = Validator::make($answer, [
       'answer.*.title' => 'required|string',
       'answer.*.question_id' => 'required|integer'
    ]);
```

Comment: I tried this validation, it gets passed and not working"